# SSAS 2012 - YTD calculated member not rolling up for all Time hier members

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

Calculated member is defined simply:

```
 Aggregate(YTD(),[Period].[CurrentPeriod])
```

This works well for all measures at the Year and the Month level - but Quarter repeats the Yearly sum rather than properly rolling up the YTD values from the months.

```
2006            300
Quarter 1 2006    300
Quarter 2 2006    300
    April 2006      100
    May 2006        100
    June 2006       100
Quarter 3 2006    300
Quarter 4 2006    300
```

Thanks for any help for this MDX newb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted this one out.  I am in the process of migrating cubes from 2000 to 2012 - this calculated member originated in 2000.  Added to the YTD function parameters slightly:

Aggregate(YTD([Time].[Time].CURRENTMEMBER),[Period].[CurrentPeriod])

This corrected the roll-up issue without further adjustment.